# Mostrar más de 9 filas de información de una base de datos en Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Quiero mostrar con *PrimeFaces* una tabla con contenido que tengo en la base de datos. Mi tabla consta de 2 campos, un campo `capítulo` que es el *ID* y un campo `row` que tiene un arreglo de valores de cada columna de la fila en formato *JSON*. De igual manera tengo vinculado al *capitulo* en otra tabla los encabezados de las columnas.

El código de mi vista es:

```
<p:dataTable id="tableData" var="rowName" value="#{historicalBean.header}" rowIndexVar="rowIdx" paginator="true" rows="15" paginatorPosition="bottom">
    <p:columns var="columnName" value="#{historicalBean.header}" headerText="#{columnName}"
               columnIndexVar="colIdx">
        <ui:repeat value="#{historicalBean.rows[rowIdx][colIdx]}" var="data" varStatus="status">
                #{data}
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

La lista `historicalBean.header` es de `String: private List<String> header;`, e `historicalBean.rows` es una *Lista de listas de String*: `private List<List<String>> rows;`

La información en las *Listas*, se inicializa correctamente porque la imprimo en la consola y al *XHTML* está llegando correctamente porque lo estoy imprimiendo en la vista y toma el valor 58 (mayor que 9) `<h3>#{historicalBean.count}</h3>`

Se está llenando la tabla correctamente pero con un problema, que solo se muestran las 9 primeras filas de la tabla. EL problema no es el paginado de la tabla, es la cantidad de filas que muestra respecto al total.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al parecer el error estaba en la declaración de la variable que itera en el 'ui:repeat' que se declara en el dataTable, el código correcto queda de esta manera:

```
<p:dataTable id="tableData" var="rowName" value="#{historicalBean.rows}" rowIndexVar="rowIdx" paginator="true" rows="15" paginatorPosition="bottom">
<p:columns var="columnName" value="#{historicalBean.header}" headerText="#{columnName}"
           columnIndexVar="colIdx">
    <ui:repeat value="#{historicalBean.rows[rowIdx][colIdx]}" var="data" varStatus="status">
            #{data}
    </ui:repeat>
</p:columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal.
Prime faces tiene un propiedad para los data tables en la cual indicas el numero de filas por pagina, esta propiedad se llama **rowsPerPageTemplate**

te dejo los ejmplos de datatable de la pagina de primefaces.

[Paginator - Rows per page](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/paginator.xhtml)

saludos!!

Comment: Gracias, pero no me sirve de mucho, esto lo único que hace es organizar de manera distinta las únicas 10 filas que lee en lugar de las 58 que son, como puedes ver en la imagen